# Looping over unique values

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame in long format, with one observation row per measurement. I want to loop through each unique ID and find the "minimum" date for each unique individual. For example, patient 1 may be measured at three different times, but I want the earliest time. I thought about sorting the dataset by the date (in increasing order) and removing all duplicates, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID', `order` the 'Date' (assuming that it is in `Date` class or else change to `Date` class with `as.Date` with correct `format`), and get the first observation with `head`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(Date), head(.SD, 1), by = ID]
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with `data.table`. What does `head(.SD, 1)` do in this case?

Comment: @user122514  `.SD` means Subset of Data.table, `head` with 1 gets the 1st row of each group after ordering by Date

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using basic R:

```
earliestDates = aggregate(list(date = df$date), list(ID = df$ID), min)
result = merge(earliestDates,df)
```

earliestDates is a two column data frame that has the minimum date by ID. The merge will join the values in the other columns.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
ID = floor(runif(20,1,5))
day = as.Date(floor(runif(20,1,25)),origin = "2017-1-1")
weight = floor(runif(20,80,95))
df = data.frame(ID = ID, date = day, weight = weight)

> df
   ID       date weight
1   2 2017-01-24     92
2   2 2017-01-07     89
3   3 2017-01-17     91
4   4 2017-01-05     88
5   1 2017-01-08     87
6   4 2017-01-11     91
7   4 2017-01-02     80
8   3 2017-01-11     87
9   3 2017-01-22     90
10  1 2017-01-10     90
11  1 2017-01-13     87
12  1 2017-01-16     92
13  3 2017-01-13     86
14  2 2017-01-06     83
15  4 2017-01-21     81
16  2 2017-01-18     81
17  3 2017-01-21     84
18  4 2017-01-04     87
19  2 2017-01-19     89
20  4 2017-01-11     86
```

After the `aggregate` and `merge`, the result is:

```
> result
  ID       date weight
1  1 2017-01-08     87
2  2 2017-01-06     83
3  3 2017-01-11     87
4  4 2017-01-02     80
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `dplyr` code:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(12345)

###Create test dataset
tb <- tibble(id = rep(1:10, each = 3), 
             date = rep(seq(as.Date("2017-07-01"), by=10, len=10), 3),
             obs = rnorm(30))

# # A tibble: 30 × 3
# id       date        obs
# <int>     <date>      <dbl>
#     1 2017-07-01  0.5855288
#     1 2017-07-11  0.7094660
#     1 2017-07-21 -0.1093033
#     2 2017-07-31 -0.4534972
#     2 2017-08-10  0.6058875
#     2 2017-08-20 -1.8179560
#     3 2017-08-30  0.6300986
#     3 2017-09-09 -0.2761841
#     3 2017-09-19 -0.2841597
#     4 2017-09-29 -0.9193220
# # ... with 20 more rows

###Pipe the dataset through dplyr's 'group_by' and 'filter' commands
tb %>% group_by(id) %>%
   filter(date == min(date)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   distinct()

# # A tibble: 10 × 3
# id       date        obs
# <int>     <date>      <dbl>
# 1        2017-07-01  0.5855288
# 2        2017-07-31 -0.4534972
# 3        2017-08-30  0.6300986
# 4        2017-07-01 -0.1162478
# 5        2017-07-21  0.3706279
# 6        2017-08-20  0.8168998
# 7        2017-07-01  0.7796219
# 8        2017-07-11  1.4557851
# 9        2017-08-10 -1.5977095
# 10       2017-09-09  0.6203798
```

Comment: Really liked this idea, as dplyr makes my code much neater. However, it is not working for my data frame. Not sure why.

Comment: Figured out what's wrong... duplicate IDs are still present, for some reason.

Comment: Hmmm, try tacking on another pipe at the end with a call to `distinct()`. Have updated answer to reflect this.